# Two questions on fractal

Tags: fractals

1. Suppose we have two given fractals $K_1$, $K_2$ of dimension $d_1$,$d_2$ respectively. What can we say about the dimension of $K_1 \cap K_2$, and $K_1 \cup K_2$?
2. Is there any technique to describe a fractal with given dimension $d$?

   3. What if the dimension is not a ration of two logarithms?

Comment: What is your definition of the term "fractal"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2 using [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension), if you review how the Koch snowflake dimension is shown to be $\frac{\log 4}{\log 3}$ you can see how to make a fractal with any dimension of the form $1<\frac{\log m}{\log n}<2$-just divide the side into $n$ pieces and replace each with $m$ segments each time.  Similarly the Cantor set has dimension $\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$ and shows how to get other ratios

For 1, the same Wikipedia article says the union has the higher dimension.  The intersection can clearly have dimension $0$ if they are disjoint and no higher than the lower.